# JPA eager fetching not returning any results

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I went through several posts but none of them worked for me. I am trying to fetch a Cnsm record and its associated cnsmPrefCntcInfos child record at the same time. I am also able to see hibernate query being generated to retrieve the child (cnsmPrefCntcInfos ) record. However, when I print CNSM, I get back an empty object.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CNSM" )
public class Cnsm implements java.io.Serializable {

private BigDecimal cnsmId;
private String cnsmFstNm;
private String cnsmMidlNm;

@Id

@Column(name = "CNSM_ID", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 22,    scale = 0)
public BigDecimal getCnsmId() {
    return this.cnsmId;
}

public void setCnsmId(BigDecimal cnsmId) {
    this.cnsmId = cnsmId;
}

@Column(name = "CNSM_FST_NM", length = 35)
public String getCnsmFstNm() {
    return this.cnsmFstNm;
}

public void setCnsmFstNm(String cnsmFstNm) {
    this.cnsmFstNm = cnsmFstNm;
}

@Column(name = "CNSM_MIDL_NM", length = 25)
public String getCnsmMidlNm() {
    return this.cnsmMidlNm;
}

public void setCnsmMidlNm(String cnsmMidlNm) {
    this.cnsmMidlNm = cnsmMidlNm;
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "cnsm")
private Set<CnsmPrefCntcInfo> cnsmPrefCntcInfos = new HashSet<CnsmPrefCntcInfo>(0);



public Set<CnsmPrefCntcInfo> getCnsmPrefCntcInfos() {
    return this.cnsmPrefCntcInfos;
}

public void setCnsmPrefCntcInfos(Set<CnsmPrefCntcInfo> cnsmPrefCntcInfos) {
    this.cnsmPrefCntcInfos = cnsmPrefCntcInfos;
}
```

}

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CNSM_PREF_CNTC_INFO")
public class CnsmPrefCntcInfo implements java.io.Serializable {



private BigDecimal cnsmPrefCntcInfoId;
private Cnsm cnsm;
private String cntcTyp;

private Set<CnsmPrefPstAdr> cnsmPrefPstAdrs = new HashSet<CnsmPrefPstAdr>(0);
private Set<CnsmPrefTelCmnct> cnsmPrefTelCmncts = new HashSet<CnsmPrefTelCmnct>(0);





@Id

@Column(name = "CNSM_PREF_CNTC_INFO_ID", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 22, scale = 0)
public BigDecimal getCnsmPrefCntcInfoId() {
    return this.cnsmPrefCntcInfoId;
}

public void setCnsmPrefCntcInfoId(BigDecimal cnsmPrefCntcInfoId) {
    this.cnsmPrefCntcInfoId = cnsmPrefCntcInfoId;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "CNSM_ID")

public Cnsm getCnsm() {
    return this.cnsm;
}

public void setCnsm(Cnsm cnsm) {
    this.cnsm = cnsm;
}

@Column(name = "CNTC_TYP", length = 50)
public String getCntcTyp() {
    return this.cntcTyp;
}

public void setCntcTyp(String cntcTyp) {
    this.cntcTyp = cntcTyp;
}



@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "cnsmPrefCntcInfo")
public Set<CnsmPrefPstAdr> getCnsmPrefPstAdrs() {
    return this.cnsmPrefPstAdrs;
}

public void setCnsmPrefPstAdrs(Set<CnsmPrefPstAdr> cnsmPrefPstAdrs) {
    this.cnsmPrefPstAdrs = cnsmPrefPstAdrs;
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "cnsmPrefCntcInfo")
public Set<CnsmPrefTelCmnct> getCnsmPrefTelCmncts() {
    return this.cnsmPrefTelCmncts;
}

public void setCnsmPrefTelCmncts(Set<CnsmPrefTelCmnct> cnsmPrefTelCmncts) {
    this.cnsmPrefTelCmncts = cnsmPrefTelCmncts;
}

}
```

Repo Service

```
@Query("SELECT c FROM Cnsm c WHERE c.id = '123'")

Cnsm findCnsmById();
```

Main class

```
  Cnsm  c = IRepository.findCnsmById();
  System.out.print(c); // returns empty cnsmPrefCntcInfos object
```

Hibernate: select cnsm0_.CNSM_ID as CNSM_ID1_4_,  cnsm0_.CNSM_FST_NM as CNSM_FST4_4_, cnsm0_.CNSM_MIDL_NM as CNSM_MID6_4_ from CNSM cnsm0_ where cnsm0_.CNSM_ID=103

*Below is the Hibernate query that is being generated to fetch cnsmPrefCntcInfos, but not sure why cnsmPrefCntcInfos comes back as empty*

**Hibernate: select cnsmprefcn0_.CNSM_ID as CNSM_ID15_4_1_, cnsmprefcn0_.CNSM_PREF_CNTC_INFO_ID as CNSM_PRE1_7_1_, cnsmprefcn0_.CNSM_PREF_CNTC_INFO_ID as CNSM_PRE1_7_0_, cnsmprefcn0_.CNSM_ID as CNSM_ID15_7_0_, cnsmprefcn0_.CNTC_TYP as CNTC_TYP2_7_0_ from CNSM_PREF_CNTC_INFO cnsmprefcn0_ where cnsmprefcn0_.CNSM_ID=?**

How do I get cnsmPrefCntcInfos(EAGER) while retrieving cnsm object? I have many such associations like cnsmPrefCntcInfos in cnsm, that I want to retrieve at the time of fetching cnsm.

Comment: you checked the database and sure you have your entries there?

Comment: do you have both table in same schema or difference schema ?

Comment: they are in the same schema

Answer (score 0):

in your Cnsm u need to change the column name of the id to "CNSM_ID", and from what i see Cnsm fetch is lazy not eager.

Comment: I already had those in my getter method but hadn't mentioned it here. I have updated my post now. and also, changing cnsm fetch to eager makes no difference.